# magento different prices for customer groups

Tags: magento-1.9, php

im creating a magento store for a B2B store. The issue im facing is that i need to have a different price for a different customer group. i have checked the built in group price feature in Magento but this is not what i need since it just shows a price for the specific groupo only when it is LOWER than the actual price and it shows it as a SPECIAL PRICE in the front end What i need is to have a different price for each customer group without showing it as a SPECIAL PRICE is that possible ? if yes how could i do that ? do i change some PHP code ?

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the price.phtml template in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml` 
(or `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`)

This is the template where the 'Special price' label is added:

```
<span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Special Price:') ?></span>
```

Copy the price.phtml to your template and edit/update it there.

The template is quite big, you might consider using a refactored price.phtml like this one: https://gist.github.com/sandermangel/de408f7bbea33c8b7771